# TikZ: New coordinates from old ones

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose that I define two points `a` and `b` in a TikZ picture, such as:

```
\coordinate (a) at (.8,0);
\coordinate (b) at (0,1.25);
```

And now suppose that I want to define a third point `c` whose first coordinate is the first coordinate of point `a` and whose second coordinate is the second coordinate of point `b`. Can it be done? And, if so, how?

Comment: Try `\coordinate (c) at (a|-b);` or, as @Schrödinger's cat suggested, `\path (a|-b) coordinate (c);`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Many thanks! I fixed it :)

Comment: @LaTeXer, also, now, coordinates have different names.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks to you also. I fixed that too :-)